# How to remove iPhone as a source device for sleep data (Apple Health)

Tags: iphone, health.app

For any app that wants to read or write data to Apple Health, I can give or refuse permission to do so. But when it comes to devices as data sources (e.g. my iPhone), I can’t seem to find any way of stopping my iPhone from writing sleep data to Apple Health.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In the Health app, tap ***Browse*** at the bottom right, there you
   choose ***Sleep***.
2. Go to Your Schedule further down, tap ***Full Schedule & Options***.
3. Scroll down to ***Additional Details***
4. Deactivate the slider at ***Track Time in Bed with iPhone***